# which is better method? map by rowid or column

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, join

Please suggest me better code

Method (A)

```
        MERGE /*+ Idx_Mrx_Strategy */INTO stgMurex m
        USING
        (
            SELECT  m.RowId  AS mRowId
            FROM    stgMurex m
            INNER JOIN LovDF_EMIR t
            ON      m.Strategy = t.Strategy
            WHERE   t.NonDF = 'Y'

        ) l
        ON (m.RowId = l.mRowId)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET
                m.DF = 'N'
        WHERE   m.DF IS NULL
        ;
```

```
Rows    Plan
199448  MERGE STATEMENT  
     MERGE  STGMUREX
      VIEW  
199448     HASH JOIN  
199448      HASH JOIN  
130      TABLE ACCESS FULL LOVDF_EMIR
576864       TABLE ACCESS FULL STGMUREX
1426340     TABLE ACCESS FULL STGMUREX
```

Method (B)

```
        MERGE INTO stgMurex m
        USING
        (
            SELECT  t.Strategy 
            FROM    LovDF_EMIR t
            WHERE   t.NonDF = 'Y'
        ) l
        ON (m.Strategy = l.Strategy)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET
                m.DF = 'N'
        WHERE m.DF IS NULL 
        ;
```

```
Rows    Plan
199448  MERGE STATEMENT  
     MERGE  STGMUREX
      VIEW  
199448     HASH JOIN  
130     TABLE ACCESS FULL LOVDF_EMIR
576864      TABLE ACCESS FULL STGMUREX
```

May I say Method B is best?

Comment: why do you use merge instead update only if you do update?

Comment: @Franek I suspect it's because Oracle does not support `JOIN` in update statements and this problem was easily solved by a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose (assuming "the percentage of successful rows returned from the driving table is small" which may be caused by "t.NonDF = 'Y'" ) the more efficient than merge with join will be:

```
UPDATE stgMurex m
SET m.DF    = 'N'
WHERE m.DF IS NULL
AND EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM LovDF_EMIR t WHERE t.NonDF = 'Y' AND m.Strategy = t.Strategy
);
```

Good explanation here: http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/4778.table-joins-versus-exists.aspx

Comment: Assume query returned from the driving table is large. Now which one is better. Method A or B?

Comment: Please provide explain plans for all three queries. It will be easier to answer your question. I suppose A and B are very similar - I would like compare them with my statement.